# Another Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Doing a loop within a loop in a view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
    <td>
        <span ng-repeat="device in helpers.getIosDevices(result.ios_device)">
            {{ device.code }}
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The controller:

```
$scope.helpers = CRM.helpers;
```

The helper:

```
var CRM = CRM || {};

CRM.helpers = {
    // Handle "111" value format
    getIosDevices: function (devices) {
        var obj = [];

        if (devices !== null && devices !== undefined) {
            if (devices.charAt(0) === '1') {
                obj.push({
                    code: 'ipod',
                    name: 'iPod',
                });
            }
            if (devices.charAt(1) === '1') {
                obj.push({
                    code: 'ipad',
                    name: 'iPad',
                });
            }
            if (devices.charAt(2) === '1') {
                obj.push({
                    code: 'iphone',
                    name: 'iPhone',
                });
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
};
```

Got this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn:%E2%80%A620%20%20%7D;%20newVal:%20undefined;%20oldVal:%20undefined%22%5D%5D

as I understand but I don't know how can I solve it in my case. What workaround should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this error that you try to change source list in `ng-repeat` directive during digest cycle.

```
<span ng-repeat="device in helpers.getIosDevices(result.ios_device)">
                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

and `obj.push(/* ... */)` in `getIosDevices`

First we need ask our self when digest cycle will stop looping: It will stop when Angular detect that on several iterations the list didn't change. In your case each time when `ng-repeat` calls `getIosDevices` method - the list gets different items and therefore it looping again till you get limit and Angular drops this exception.

---

**So what is a solution:**

In Angular its not good practice to call method *getList()* in `ngRepeat`. Because developpers make bugs.

Its clear that in your case `getIosDevices()` list depends on `results` therefore I would create different *fixed* object with some watcher on `results` and write HTML part like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
    <td>
        <span ng-repeat="device in devices[result.ios_device]">
            {{ device.code }}
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

where `devices` represents Map.

---

This is some demo that might help you:

```
$scope.results = [{
        ios_device: "100"
    }, {
        ios_device: "010"
    }, {
        ios_device: "001"
    }];


    $scope.devices = {
        "100": [{
            code: 'ipod',
            name: 'iPod1',
        },
               {
            code: 'ipod',
            name: 'iPod2',
        }],
            "010": [{
            code: 'ipod',
            name: 'iPod1',
        },
               {
            code: 'ipad',
            name: 'iPad2',
        }],
            "001": [{
            code: 'ipod',
            name: 'iPod1',
        },
               {
            code: 'iphone',
            name: 'iphone2',
        }],
    }
```

*HTML*

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
        <td><span ng-repeat="device in devices[result.ios_device]">
        {{ device.code }}
    </span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo in <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2570/)**</kbd>

Comment: Then how to rewrite this to avoid the exception? In most cases, the created array is always the same.

Comment: @sylouuu added some demo